# PHP Validation Error Not Showing On Dropdown

Tags: php, html

How come I cannot get the error to show on the code below the `select` posts fine

**PHP Validation:**

```
if ($movie == "select") {
            $errormovie .= 'Please select a favourite movie';
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<select name='movie' id="movie">
                        <option value="select" >Select your favourite movie:</option>
                        <option value="Smokey and the Bandit 1977" <?php selected(@$movie, 1) ?>>Smokey and the Bandit 1977</option>
                        <option value="Good Morning, Vietnam " <?php selected(@$movie, 2) ?>>Good Morning, Vietnam </option>
                        <option value="Big Trouble in Little China 1986" <?php selected(@$movie, 3) ?>>Big Trouble in Little China 1986</option>
                        <option value="Dead Poets Society 1989" <?php selected(@$movie, 4) ?>>Dead Poets Society 1989</option>
                        <option value="Braveheart 1995" <?php selected(@$movie, 5) ?>>Braveheart 1995</option>
                        <option value="Black Sheep 1996" <?php selected(@$movie, 6) ?>>Black Sheep 1996</option>
                        <option value="What Dreams May Come 1998" <?php selected(@$movie, 7) ?>>What Dreams May Come 1998</option>
                        <option value="Patch Adams 1998" <?php selected(@$movie, 8) ?>>Patch Adams 1998</option>  
                        <option value="The Green Mile 1999" <?php selected(@$movie, 9) ?>>The Green Mile 1999</option>
                        <option value="Jakob the Liar 1999" <?php selected(@$movie, 10) ?>>Jakob the Liar 1999 </option>
                        <option value="The Skulls 2000" <?php selected(@$movie, 11) ?>>The Skulls 2000</option>
                        <option value="Kangaroo Jack 2003" <?php selected(@$movie, 12) ?>>Kangaroo Jack 2003</option>
                        <option value="The Butterfly Effect 2004" <?php selected(@$movie, 13) ?>>The Butterfly Effect 2004</option>
                        <option value="Starsky and Hutch 2004" <?php selected(@$movie, 14) ?>>Starsky and Hutch 2004</option>
                        <option value="Slumdog Millionaire 2008" <?php selected(@$movie, 15) ?>>Slumdog Millionaire 2008</option>
                        <option value="Inception 2010" <?php selected(@$movie, 16) ?>>Inception 2010</option>     
                        <option value="The Hunger Games 2012" <?php selected(@$movie, 17) ?>>The Hunger Games 2012</option> 


<span class="error">* <?php echo $errormovie;?></span>  


</select>
```

Comment: Where do you put the php validation and thanks for the list movies though ;)

Comment: @user3350731 the validation goes above the <html> in the head :P

Comment: Are you posting back to the same page? If so are you using $_POST to get the value of movie?

Comment: @ShaneA.Darr Yes and movie shows the select value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that is your actual code, then you have put your `span` element *inside* the `select` element, which would of course be nonsense – `select` can have only `option` or `optgroup` elements as children … and therefor the browser will simply ignore the `span` element at this position.

Place it *outside* of the `select` element.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot to go on from your code snippet, but if I had to guess, I'd say that your incorrectly assuming that $movie variable has a value of "select". Try using the [var_dump](http://www.php.net/var_dump) function to inspect the contents of the $movie variable.

Comment: try wapping $movie in trim. if( trim($movie) == "select")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($_POST["movie"] == "select") {
        $errormovie .= 'Please select a favourite movie';
    }
```

Comment: Will do but $movie does var_dump and show select so the $movie = $_POST["Movie"] does work

Comment: IT should be:  $movie = $_POST["movie"] (no capital letters)